# Map colors to labels in plotly go.Pie charts

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am plotting a series of 3 pie charts using make_subplots and go.Pie. I want to eventually put these in a dash app where the user can filter the data and the figure will update. How can I map specific colors to variables so that Male is always blue, Female is always pink, etc. You can do this with plotly express with color_discrete_map but plotly express doesn't support subplots afaik.

Here is an example df that I make the gender pie chart from. The other dfs have the same format just different values.

```
    Gender  ACC_ID  percent
0   Female  57647   57.0
1   Male    37715   37.0
2   Other   5875    6.0
```

And here is the code I use to make the figures

```
fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=3, specs=[[{'type':'domain'}, {'type':'domain'},{'type':'domain'}]])
fig.add_trace(go.Pie(labels=age["Age_Group"], values=age["percent"],customdata=age["ACC_ID"], textinfo='label+percent',insidetextorientation='horizontal', textfont=dict(color='#000000'), marker_colors=px.colors.qualitative.Plotly),
              1, 1)
fig.add_trace(go.Pie(labels=gender["Gender"], values=gender["percent"], customdata=gender["ACC_ID"],textinfo='label+percent',insidetextorientation='horizontal',textfont=dict(color='#000000'),marker_colors=px.colors.qualitative.Plotly),
              1, 2)
fig.add_trace(go.Pie(labels=sample["Sample_Type"], values=sample["percent"], customdata=sample["ACC_ID"],textinfo='label+percent',texttemplate='%{label}<br>%{percent:.1%f}',insidetextorientation='horizontal',textfont=dict(color='#000000'),marker_colors=px.colors.qualitative.Prism),
              1, 3)


fig.update_traces(hole=.4, hoverinfo='label+percent', hovertemplate="<b>%{label}</b><br>Percent: %{percent}<br>Total: %{customdata}<extra></extra>")

fig.update_layout(
    showlegend=False,
    uniformtext_minsize=14, 
    uniformtext_mode='hide',

    annotations=[dict(text='Age', x=0.13, y=0.5, font_size=20, showarrow=False, font=dict(color="black")),
                 dict(text='Gender', x=0.5, y=0.5, font_size=20, showarrow=False,font=dict(color="black")),
                 dict(text='Sample', x=0.879, y=0.5, font_size=20, showarrow=False,font=dict(color="black"))])
    

plot(fig)
```

Answer (score 6):

Without Plotly Express, you could try the following:

- Stop go.Pie() from sorting your data by adding:

  ```
  sort=False
  ```
- Define the colours:

  ```
  fig.update_traces(marker=dict(colors=['blue', 'red', 'green']))
  ```

It is not as clean as color_discrete_map though.

Answer (score 6):

You can actually use the argument **marker_colors** from *go.Pie()* to map values (colors) to labels. You just need to create a *dict* correlating **label:color** and use it like that:

```
gender_color = {'Female':'pink', 'Male':'blue', 'Other':'yellow'}

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=3, specs=[[{'type':'domain'}, {'type':'domain'},{'type':'domain'}]])
fig.add_trace(go.Pie(labels=age["Age_Group"], values=age["percent"],customdata=age["ACC_ID"], textinfo='label+percent',insidetextorientation='horizontal', textfont=dict(color='#000000'), marker_colors=px.colors.qualitative.Plotly),1, 1)
fig.add_trace(go.Pie(labels=gender["Gender"], values=gender["percent"], customdata=gender["ACC_ID"],textinfo='label+percent',insidetextorientation='horizontal',textfont=dict(color='#000000'),marker_colors=gender["Gender"].map(gender_color)),1, 2)
fig.add_trace(go.Pie(labels=sample["Sample_Type"], values=sample["percent"], customdata=sample["ACC_ID"],textinfo='label+percent',texttemplate='%{label}<br>%{percent:.1%f}',insidetextorientation='horizontal',textfont=dict(color='#000000'),marker_colors=px.colors.qualitative.Prism),1, 3)

fig.update_traces(hole=.4, hoverinfo='label+percent', hovertemplate="<b>%{label}</b><br>Percent: %{percent}<br>Total: %{customdata}<extra></extra>")

fig.update_layout(
    showlegend=False,
    uniformtext_minsize=14, 
    uniformtext_mode='hide',

    annotations=[dict(text='Age', x=0.13, y=0.5, font_size=20, showarrow=False, font=dict(color="black")),
                 dict(text='Gender', x=0.5, y=0.5, font_size=20, showarrow=False,font=dict(color="black")),
                 dict(text='Sample', x=0.879, y=0.5, font_size=20, showarrow=False,font=dict(color="black"))])
plot(fig)
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that [color_discrete_map](https://plotly.com/python/discrete-color/#directly-mapping-colors-to-data-values) is what you're after.

You can create a dictionary with the desired tags as keys and corresponding color HEX codes as values.

```
palette = {"Male": "#0064FF","Female":"#FF8FDF", "Other": "#FFC300"}
```

Then pass it as a parameter into your pie() chart.

Would love to answer in more details but you need to provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)..

Comment: I'm Plotly newbie and still struggling with what niche `go`, `ff` and `px` take, but isn't `color_discrete_map` something related exclusively to `px` only, but question is explicitly related to `go`? I'm asking because I'm trying to hard-glue colors in my pie chart, but had to use `go` because [basic example](https://plotly.com/python/pie-charts/#basic-pie-chart-with-gopie) based on `go` while [colors example](https://plotly.com/python/pie-charts/#using-an-explicit-mapping-for-discrete-colors) uses `px` 

Comment: The short answer would be that anything you can do with PX you can do with GO. PX is a higher level wrapper for GO so it uses go under the hood. FF on the other hand is used to create very specific types of plots that at the time of their creation were difficult to implement with GO. [Styled Pie Chart](https://plotly.com/python/pie-charts/) example is using GO with hardcoded color sequence. You can also use camps instead of the list in the example.

Comment: I don't think this works.

Comment: One thing I've noticed is that you have the ```color='<column_name>'``` argument set for the ```color_discrete_map=<color_map_dict>```to work.