# Keeping the same legend while changing the palette in go.Pie subplot

Tags: python, pie-chart, subplot, plotly-python, color-palette

I am trying to make a `subplot` with two pies, and I have trouble keeping the same `legend` for both of them while changing the `palette` (although it works fine with plotly default `palette`)

There are the two dataframes I am working with. They are made with a `value_counts` and therefore are sorted.

```
yearly = pd.DataFrame(data={'index': ['A', 'B','C','D'], 'count': [3000, 2000,1000,50]})
monthly = pd.DataFrame(data={'index': ['B', 'A','C','D'], 'count': [250, 200,80,10]})
```

`index` `A` and `B` are reversed in the two dfs.

Then if I do :

```
fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, specs=[[{"type": "pie"}, {"type": "pie"}]])

fig.add_trace(go.Pie(
     values=monthly['count'],
     labels=monthly['index'].astype(str),
     title='Monthly'), 
     row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Pie(
     values=yearly['count'],
     labels=yearly['index'].astype(str),
     title="yearly",),
    row=1, col=2)

fig.update_layout(legend=dict(x=0.4))
                  
fig.update_traces(textposition='inside', textinfo='percent+label')                  
fig.show()
```

it works fine, I have the same `legend` for both charts (ie every index has the same color on both charts)

[Result with defaut palette = what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZJrd.png)

But, if I try to change the `palette` and change the `fig.update_trace` to this

```
fig.update_traces(textposition='inside', textinfo='percent+label'
                  ,marker=dict(colors=["#93C572","#CD5C5C","#F49D37","#3C6C82"]))
```

It does not work anymore. `A` and `B` do not have the same `color` on both charts and the `legend` accounts only for the first chart.

[result with custom palette = legend not shared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5OgB.png)

And I don't understand why. Otherwise, I will end up sorting the `df` so that the index is always in the same order (A, B, C, D) but I am sure there is a more elegant way.

I have tried the solutions of this thread [Map colors to labels in plotly go.Pie charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63162423/map-colors-to-labels-in-plotly-go-pie-charts) but it did not work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, please always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags. Also read the tag wiki on [tag:plotly], it tells you to use [tag:plotly-python] instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you intend to do since there is no image that includes a specific legend, but I think the issue would be solved if each subplot unit had its own legend. Your intended subplot is one row and two columns, but the legend appears above and below. This seems to be the default behavior for pie chart subplots. To improve this, I have made it 2 rows and 1 column. Also, I have opened up the space between the legends to align them with the subplots.

```
fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, specs=[[{"type": "pie"}], [{"type": "pie"}]])

fig.add_trace(go.Pie(
     values=monthly['count'],
     labels=monthly['index'].astype(str),
    title='Monthly', legendgroup='gr1'),
     row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Pie(
     values=yearly['count'],
     labels=yearly['index'].astype(str),
     title="yearly", legendgroup='gr2'),
    row=2, col=1)

# fig.update_traces(textposition='inside', textinfo='percent+label'
#                   ,marker=dict(colors=["#93C572","#CD5C5C","#F49D37","#3C6C82"]))

fig.update_traces(textposition='inside', textinfo='percent+label')
fig.update_layout(height=600, width=500, legend_tracegroupgap=180)
fig.show()
```

[image]

In my response, I have aligned the pie charts vertically, as the following image will appear if the pie charts are aligned horizontally.

```
fig.update_layout(autosize=False, width=450, legend=dict(yanchor='top', y=0.85, tracegroupgap=35))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this quick answer. I have changed the screenshots to add the legend as you suggested and tried to make the text clearer. I am a bit reluctant to do a 2 rows and 1 column chart for the purpose of uniformity (I would have to change all of the other charts of my report). But I guess that I can still use the legendgroup option in a horizontal chart, with two separated legend instead of one shared one.

Comment: I have added a horizontal example. We have made it vertical to avoid this condition.